Label the last bar in a stacked bar plot in matplotlib/pandas
Instead of a legend, I want to label just the last bar plot of a stacked bar chart like in the image below:

I tried the code below, but instead of labelling just the last bar, it labelled only the lowest stack across all the bars.
handles, legend_labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for c, l in zip(ax.containers, legend_labels):
    ax.bar_label(ax.containers[-1], labels=legend_labels, label_type='center')


There are several issues here: you don't provide test data nor code to create the stacked bars.  You also seem to have both negative and positive bars:  are they strictly separated? What do you propose when the area is much too narrow for the text?  Maybe you want to try something like for cnt, lbl in zip(ax.containers, legend_labels): ax.bar_label(cnt, labels=['']*(len(cnt)-1)+[lbl], label_type='center')?
